# Javascript set input text field to value not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to clear an input text field in JavaScript, but I can't get it to work.

html:

```
<div class="myclass" id="text_answer"><input type="text" /></div>
```

js:

```
function clearAnswerArea(){
    var answerBoxItem = document.getElementById("text_answer");
    console.log("value:"+answerBoxItem.value+" box: "+answerBoxItem); 
    answerBoxItem.value = "";  #does nothing
    #answerBoxItem.innerHTML = ""; #this hides the text field
    answerBoxItem.setAttribute("style","background-color:"+yellowBoxColour); #this sets the background behind the text field to yellow
```

}

I typed in some text into the text box then reloaded the page which in turn calls the clearAnswerArea function but in the console I get:

```
value:undefined box: [object HTMLDivElement]
```

The text is still in the text box. I know I am using the correct id as the background colour is being set.

Any clues?

Comment: `answerBoxItem` is the *div* not `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> answerBoxItem.value = "";  #does nothing

This will not do anything because **answerBoxItem** is a `div` not an `input` element and `div`'s don't have `value` attribute/property.

If you want to clear the input field inside answerBoxItem then try

```
answerBoxItem.children[0].value = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> document.getElementById("text_answer");
> ```

That gets the element with the matching ID.

> ```
> <div class="myclass" id="text_answer">
> ```

Which is a div.

Divs do not have `value` properties.

You need to get the input.

```
var answerBoxItem = document.querySelector("#text_answer input");
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear the item with the id - this id is on the parent div - not the input - so either change the selector or change the code - for example - putting the id into the input not the parent div:

```
<div class="myclass"><input type="text" id="text_answer" name="text-answer" /></div>
```